# Is it possible to reroute pre-existing image links due to dead domain?

Tags: javascript, html, http, web

I have, erroneously used a free site to host images, and have sent out a number of emails with this linked image in them. The URL has now disappeared and therefore all my emails show 404 for the image.

I really think that it is impossible, but is there any way to reroute this bad link to a good link? Obviously I cannot add anything to these emails. This is more about intercepting the call. If I controlled the target domain, I could probably add an A Record to reroute, but I do not.

I am just asking incase for some extreme reason there is an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For some extreme reason, have you got control over the client devices from where the mails are being read? Or are all of them within the same network?

Comment: if you don’t control the domain, and you can't edit the documents with the links (the emails), and you don’t control the network the recipients are on, then no. Your question then becomes equivalent to asking, “If random people try to go to facebook.com, can I redirect them to my own site instead?” — and the answer is “gosh, i hope not, because then the Internet is broken”

Comment: Do try to buy the domain name if it becomes available, though. That would solve your problem. Maybe you can even buy it from the current owner directly.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, this is not possible
because if it were, anyone would have anticipated an email call route and processed stuff in accordance.

If you can get to your old server, you can redirect your emails from there to new route but since you have lost it, I dont think this is any possibility for that anymore.

maybe contact site administration for help.

Comment: Thanks for all comments suspected this be outcome. Bizarrely and fortunately links working again this morning. I no longer use this service for future emails.